# Valued fields with quantifier elimination in the Macintyre language

Tags: model-theory, valuation-theory

For which fields $k$ of characteristic $p$ does the Witt construction of a discretely valued field $W(k)$ of characteristic $0$ with residue field $k$ eliminate quantifiers in the language of rings together with an $n$th power predicate for each $n$? This holds for $k=\mathbb{F}_p$, and I'm wondering if it holds for a broader class of fields (e.g. all finite fields? What about algebraically closed fields of characteristic $p$?)